# Problema utilizando toFixed para arredondar valor

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando a função **toFixed()** do javascript para exibir valores com duas casas decimais (**toFixed(2)** para exibir 2 dígitos após a ponto decimal).

O problema ocorre que tenho duas situações onde o valor possui três dígitos após a ponto decimal, na qual termina com o número 5 e o comportamento de arredondamento é diferente de ambas. Um ele aplica a regra:

*"Se o algarismo anterior ao da casa decimal que você quer arredondar for maior ou igual a 5, devemos aumentar 1 na casa decimal escolhida para o arredondamento. Se o número for menor do que 5, é só tirarmos as casas decimais que não nos interessam, e o número não se altera."*

Só que o outro não aplica.

Exemplo

```js
console.log('Resultado: ' + 6.825.toFixed(2))
console.log('Resultado: ' + 4.925.toFixed(2))
```

Ambos deveriam ter o mesmo comportamento, alguém já passou por esse problema?

**Observação:** Já tentei utilizar a função **toPrecision()** mas não resolveu para mim.

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo outras buscas, consegui resolver o problema utilizando o Math.round()

Para o problema de arredondamento devido a aritmética de ponto flutuante imprecisa, foi necessário usar a função da seguinte forma

**Math.round(nro*100)/100**

```js
console.log(Math.round(4.925 * 100) / 100)
console.log(Math.round(6.825 * 100) / 100)
```

**Fonte:** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round